# AWS - Postfix / RSYSLOG - CONNECT from unknown

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, amazon-web-services, rsyslog

Getting several of these in my mail log:

`lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[10.3.47.5]`

10.3.47.5 isn't within my DNS and I cannot determine the hostname, nor can I ssh into it. Is it safe to assume this is one of the multiple IPS within a ELB used to check the status of the postfix service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the EC2 console, find **Network Interfaces** in the left sidebar menu and click on it.

On the list of network interfaces, you should be able to find this address in the Primary Private IP column.

If it is an ELB interface, the name of the ELB will be shown under **Description**.